# Is there a Linux desktop key logger application that can monitor how long I spend on websites and desktop applications?

Tags: monitoring, time-management

I am looking for a key logger application monitoring application that can tell me:

- How long I have spent using a desktop
  application
- How long I have spent on each website
  I visit via my browsers

Does anyone know of such an application?

**UPDATE** I forgot to mention it has to be Linux compatible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wakoopa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyzoA.png) fits the bill.

[image]

Comment: I don't think I want to know...

Answer (score 3):

[RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com/) is a great app that I've used to analyze this and increase my productivity.

Comment: its only for mac or windows

Comment: RescireTime has a linux client:  https://launchpad.net/rescuetime-linux-uploader

Answer (score 1):

Try [spectorsoft](http://www.spectorsoft.com/products/SpectorPro_Windows/entry.asp?refer=12080)

Comment: its only for Windows. I specifically wrote Linux in my question.

Comment: Ya, ok, you updated the post on the 26th. I answered on the 24th.